# How to fit El Nino SST data (as an exogenous data) in ARIMA modeling in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am working on time series forecasting of monthly averaged rainfall data (from a rainfall subdivision in India) using ARIMA methodology in R. But, in order to improve the forecast result, I want to include the (time series) data from El Niño Sea Surface Temperature (SST) data as an exogenous input in ARIMA model. Currently, I have the SST time series data with me, but I'm struggling with how to incorporate these data inputs as "xreg" in my ARIMA model i.e can I directly use the SST anomaly data values in "xreg"?

This is my data:-

```
    ts.rain1 <- ts(RData$Rainfall, frequency = 12, start = c(1950,1))
    ts.nino <- ts(NData$SST, frequency = 12, start = c(1949,1))
```

Training and Test sets:-

```
    data.train <- window(ts.rain1, start = c(1950,1), end = c(1995,12))
    data.test <- window(ts.rain1, start = c(1996,1))
    ninodata.train <- window(ts.nino, start = c(1949,4), end = c(1995,3))
    ninodata.test <- window(ts.nino, start = c(1995,4))
```

And the arima code:-

```
    arima2 <- Arima(data.train, order = c(4,0,4), seasonal = list(order = c(2,0,1)), xreg = ninodata.train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. If you simply feed the data into `xreg`, then `Arima()` will fit a regression on your predictor with ARIMA errors. (This is *not* an ARIMAX model. [See here.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/))

I would recommend that you use `auto.arima()` from the `forecast` package, which will try to automatically find the best model. An ARMA(4,4) model looks rather large to me.

We have [quite a few related threads here at CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=xreg%20arima). I'd recommend you browse through them.

Comment: Hello Sir, can you please explain to me what is "fit a regression on your predictor with ARIMA errors".

Comment: `Arima()` will fit a regression of your dependent variable on the predictor(s) you feed into `xreg`.  After that, it will fit an ARIMA model to the residuals of the regression.